# Retrieving custom UUIDs from remote Bluetooth Android Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am attempting to retrieve (service) UUIDs from a remote device that is either paired or unpaired. Both the remote and local device run the same program and can successfully establish a socket for transferring data. However, on both devices only the default pre-existing UUIDs are fetched. 
I was able to see the app-specific UUID, but only once or twice out of dozens of UUID listings through [fetchUuidsWithSdp()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#fetchUuidsWithSdp()).

So my question is. Why does my custom/app-specific UUID not show up in the list of UUIDs present through [bluetoothDevice.getUuids()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids())? And when it does show up (very rarely), I am not able to replicate the behavior?

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {
    Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "Discovery finished.");
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
    }
}
```

...

```
if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    for (ParcelUuid uuid : device.getUuids()) {
        Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "action uuid: "+uuid);
    }
}
```

Log output:

> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 11-28 15:55:03.910  15893-15893/com.KoMark.Koala I/KComm﹕ action uuid:
>   00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Client creates a connection successfully:

```
        public ClientThread(BluetoothDevice device ) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        try {
            tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(KOALA_UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        }
```

And the UUID is:

```
private static final String KOALA_UUID = "e519c52c-81fb-11e5-8bcf-feff819cdc9f";
```

Comment: @MrsEd - I was able to figure it out. The bluetooth connection was established in a background service that was not terminated correctly, resulting in the "UUID" being utilized (is my guess). Thus it was not listed through service discovery.
Does that make sense?